# Get less attribute off model through relation

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two model user and course and user id foreign key in course. I need only id and username of user. My code give me all model of user having id and username and other fields are null. I don't need other fields. Just need id and username

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->select(['id', 'username']);
}

Output is:
{
    id:1
    name:ABC
    users: {[
        {
            id:1,
            username:bell,
            fist_name: null,
            last_name: null,
             ..
             ..
        },
    ]}
}



Need Output like this:
{
    id: 1,
    name: ABC,
    users: {[
        {
            id:1,
            username:bell,
        },
        {
            id:2,
            username:carson,
        },
     ]}
}
```

Comment: your query with applied `users` join?

Comment: Are you fetching this data from a REST endpoint?